# Stop Win 10 indexing without losing media streaming?

Tags: windows-10, search, streaming

As I have other fast search programs which I prefer, ideally I'd like to turn off the search indexing service in Windows 10 altogether to increase performance.

But doing so (by disabling Services > Windows Search) unfortunately also switches off the facility to use media streaming. So I couldn't watch videos/DVDs wirelessly from my PC HD on my lounge TV.

I have instead removed all the indexing targets (using Control Panel > Indexing Options). But I haven't given up on finding a purist 'completely off' solution, without that unacceptable penalty. Anyone have any suggestions on how that might be achieved please?

Comment: Please don't include signatures/taglines in your posts. That is what your profile is for.

Comment: Which program or service are you using to stream to your TV?  I'd think that, certainly if you use a different service or application, like VLC or Kodi, it might work without indexing.  I'm just trying to wrap my head around how Windows indexing is affecting streaming at all.

Comment: It took me a long time to get my streaming set up this way to my Panasonic TX-40CX800 40" LCD so I'd be reluctant to adopt another method unless I had detailed step-by-step instructions.
Streaming is a dependency of the Windows Search service:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4019461/StreamingNeedsSearch-1.jpg